# Retrieve customer with Angular and Stripe

Tags: angularjs, stripe-payments

Is there a way I can retrieve the customer information in the front-end using Angular, angular-stripe and Stripe.

I want to update the credit card information for a customer but I cant retrieve the customer from Stripe.

I'm able to publish my key

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('STRIPE-KEY');
```

Also I'm able to create a toke using:

```
Stripe.card.createToken({
    number: paymentInfo.cardNumber || '',
    cvc: paymentInfo.securityCode || '',
    exp_month: paymentInfo.month || '',
    exp_year: paymentInfo.year || '',
    name: paymentInfo.holderName || ''
}, stripeResponseHandler);
```

The response is good, with all the information an a token.
But what is I want to create a new customer or update an existing one?
Is there a method from the API to do it?

Comment: Did you try anything? are you getting errors? It's a good idea to post the code you have so far. [Here's a good place to start](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#update_card)

Comment: To retrieve the Stripe customer, you need to use your secret API key. Thus Stripe recommends that you (**EDIT**) **don't** do this on the browser, since you would expose that secret key to the outside world. 
 You need to get the Stripe customer on the server, optionally store relevant information in your database, and send the customer data to the client.

Comment: Ok, so my server returns the customer ID. How do I fetch the information from Stripe in the front-end ?

Comment: You do not fetch the information on the client. Again, that requires using your Stripe secret key. Putting that key in your Javascript means anyone can see it. Send the token you got from the code above to your server, and then your server will fetch the Stripe customer and add the card to it.

Comment: The same goes when editing a customer? or customer credit card?
I shall create a new token and send it to server so server updates the customer?

Comment: Yes, generally, the only thing you're doing in the browser with Stripe is using their Javascript code to exchange the user's credit card # for a token. The rest of the activities need to happen on the server, so you can keep your secret key a secret.

Comment: So bottom line, front-end will only create tokens when creating or updating customer and credit cards.
Server will handle all the update, create and associate stuff.
Also server will fetch the information and pass it to the front-end to display, right?